# How can I modify field inside Expression?

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I want to generate a method that will be similar to this:

```
void Add(ref MyStruct a, MyStruct b)
{
    a.Field1 += b.Field1;
    // a.Field2 += b.Field2; // and so on
}
```

To do so I declared my custom delegate:

```
public delegate void Add<T>(ref T a, T b) where T : struct;
```

and write my expression builder:

```
public static Expression<Add<T>> BuildExpression<T>() where T : struct
{
    var t = typeof(T);
    var a = Expression.Parameter(t.MakeByRefType(), "a");
    var b = Expression.Parameter(t, "b");

    return Expression.Lambda<Add<T>>(
        Expression.Block(
            t.GetFields().Select(f => 
                Expression.AddAssign(Expression.Field(a, f), Expression.Field(b, f)))),
        a, b
      );
}
```

I've added `MyStruct` with a single field `Field1` to test it. When I inspect the `DebugView` of my expression it looks very similar to expected result:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<Program+Add`1[Program+MyStruct]>(
    Program+MyStruct& $a,
    Program+MyStruct $b) {
    .Block() {
        $a.Field1 += $b.Field1
    }
}
```

however it does not modify first argument. Please see [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N4Qwqz)

So what I'm doing wrong in my `BuildExpression`?